# Combining JSON objects live

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that is getting continuously appended with new data.  Each time it gets updated I need it to be "well-formed".  The problem is that my JSON looks like this (each item is dumped serially):

```
{"one": 1},
{"two": 2}
```

I need the data to be properly formed so enclosing in square brackets could work, or an outer curly bracket.  But I'm not quite sure how to do that.

```
[
  {"one": 1},
  {"two": 2}
]
```

Here is the code performing the JSON writing:

```
def printJSONFile(data):

    json_dump = json.dumps(data, default=serialize)

    try:     
        jf = open(fullpath, "a+")
        jf.write(json_dump + ",\n")
        jf.close()
    except IOError:
        print "ERROR: Unable to open/write to {}".format(fullpath)
        return
```

Comment: Your code does exactly what you've asked it to. If you want to save a JSON array, you need to build a `list` and serialise that.

Comment: You're actively writing an invalid format... Why??

Comment: If you dropped the comma before the newline, you would at least have JDONlines format which can be useful for large amounts of data

Comment: @jonsharpe Can you point me to an example?

Comment: @roganjosh I'm trying to fix my invalid format code.  Because I'm building this list as items are being added, I'm struggling to figure out the coding pattern required.

Comment: Perhaps I can just send the last properly formatted object instead of the whole thing...

Comment: Change `",\n"` to just `"\n"`. That way, each line is valid JSON and you can iterate through the file rather than load the whole JSON data into memory to parse it

Comment: Yeah, that's what I started with.  Copy.